# Check if items are completely visible in the RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-scroll

I'm trying to check if some specific items are visible in the `RecyclerView`; But I couldn't implement that. Please help me to determine if my items are completely visible in the `RecyclerView`.

```
mrecylerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(dx, dy);
        if (ll != null) {
            TextureVideoView tvv = (TextureVideoView) ll.findViewById(R.id.cropTextureView);
        }
    }
});
```

I want to check if `tvv` view is completely visible within the `mrecyclerView` view.

Answer (score 23):

You could make some logic using the `LayoutManager` api to get the last completely visible item position in RecyclerView `onScrolled` method:

###### Kotlin

```
(vYourRecycler.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
```

###### Java

```
((LinearLayoutManager) vYourRecycler.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

From the documentation:

> Returns the adapter position of the last fully visible view. This
> position does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after
> the last layout pass.

Try to use it and notify the RecyclerView adapter to refresh.

Note: i don't know why you're using `findViewById` in `onScrolled` method, this work should be implemented in RecyclerView **ViewHolder** to improve performances

Comment: findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(); gives me last attached item, whether that is visible or not.

Comment: is this possible for `all visible item` instead of `last visible item`?

Comment: looks like to get `all visible item` is possible by iterating/looping between `first visible item index position` & `last visible item index position`, see here for more details: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35392153/3763032

Comment: @mochadwi That's exactly what I was gonna say.

Answer (score 3):

you have to set [`LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager) for `RecyclerView`. if you are using most common [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager), then it have some methods for your purpose:

- findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
- findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
- findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
- findLastVisibleItemPosition()

There are also similar methods in [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager), e.g. [findFirstVisibleItemPositions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager#findFirstVisibleItemPositions(int%5B%5D))

And general way would be to use bare `LayoutManager` and its [isViewPartiallyVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#isViewPartiallyVisible(android.view.View,%20boolean,%20boolean)) method, but this probably needs more your code for particular use case