# Know whether a view is completely visible in a recycler view from its adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I saw a lot of posts that show the currently entirely visible item in the recycler view but, from the activity. But, I want to know about that from the adapter. If the view is completely visible, I want to start playing a video and when it is hidden, I want to stop it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if items are completely visible in the RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862189/check-if-items-are-completely-visible-in-the-recyclerview)

Comment: No @a_local_nobody. I want to check it from the adapter itself. Not activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set [`LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager) for `RecyclerView`. if you are using most common [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager), then it's have some methods for your purpose:

- findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
- findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
- findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
- findLastVisibleItemPosition()

There are also similar methods in [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager), e.g. [findFirstVisibleItemPositions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager#findFirstVisibleItemPositions(int%5B%5D))

And general way would be to use bare `LayoutManager` and its [isViewPartiallyVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#isViewPartiallyVisible(android.view.View,%20boolean,%20boolean)) method, but this probably needs more your code for particular use case

Comment: Yes. I did see that. But, how can I do so from the adapter itself?

Comment: well, you may pass `LayoutManager` instance set to `RecyclerView` also to adapter in e.g. constructor. but I would do this in `Activity`/`Fragment`, as you also need some scroll listener, which would check every `10dp`s of scroll if first item was previously only "visible" and now became "completelyVisible"

Comment: btw. you "want to" do this inside adapter, but thats not a job for adapter itself. it is desired to produce list items only, not managing scrolling and visibility changes (thats job for `LayoutManager` and `RecyclerView`)

Comment: I got it. I passed the object and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps worth writing this as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862189/check-if-items-are-completely-visible-in-the-recyclerview) instead and just deleting this post