# How to handle exo players in recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How can we use multiple exo player in a recycler view? I saw many posts and videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsxZrMXzYzo) and [this](https://androidwave.com/exoplayer-in-recyclerview-in-android) but that all use a custom recycler view class. I could continue with that. But, I wanted to make a complete Insta clone where I can send gif and image and videos. Now, when I use the custom recycler view class, I dont have any idea of how to play the video with the gif and images. This is my recycler view item code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.sambhav2358.facebookclone.customviews.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/senderImage"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:cornerRadius="100dp"
                android:src="@color/primary"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/senderName"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Sender name"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dateAdded"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Date added"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/senderUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sender user name"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/more"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Body\nOf\nThe\nPost"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/postExtra"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageVIew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <com.giphy.sdk.ui.views.GifView
                android:id="@+id/gifView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/primary">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/like"
                        app:tint="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Like"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"/>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/primary">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/share"
                        app:tint="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Share"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/primary">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/comment"
                        app:tint="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Comment"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What problem Are you facing with native `RecyclerView`? u will be using a separate layout for these items with a Scroll listener so that if an video item goes out of the screen you can stop the video.

Comment: @ADM  Yes. Exactly. How do I do that. When the video is out of screen. Pause it and when its visible, start it. And I dont use a separate layout. I have all of them in the same layout

Comment: Do not use single view . Use separate views for different item. Layoutmanger has all the methods to check item visibility . [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862189/check-if-items-are-completely-visible-in-the-recyclerview).

Comment: Ok. I get it. Now, how can I play the video based on the posisition?

Comment: @ADM I got it. Just check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I just made a class where I created an static `var?` of `ExoPlayer` class which looked like this:

```kotlin
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak", "Deprecation")
class ExoPlayerPlaybackHelper {
    companion object{
        var playerView : ExoPlayer? = null
    }
}
```

Then, I used this in my model(`data` class) to create an object of `ExoPlayer` with a play function in it and in the end, my model looked like this:

```kotlin
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.sambhav2358.facebookclone.utils.ExoPlayerPlaybackHelper

data class Post(my params, var playerView: ExoPlayer?){
    fun playVideo(playerView : ExoPlayer) {
        ExoPlayerPlaybackHelper.playerView?.pause()

        ExoPlayerPlaybackHelper.playerView = playerView

        playerView.play()
    }

    constructor() : this(my params, null) //passing the ExoPlayer object null for now
}
```

Now, in the adapter, I pass my exo player to my data class's object like this:

```
post.playerView = binding.videoView.player as ExoPlayer
```

The last task was to stop and play the video according to the scroll position using the `OnScrollListener`. I used this code and it did the task for me:

```kotlin
binding.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {

                val pos = (recyclerView.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

                if (pos == -1) return

                Log.d(TAG, "onScrolled: Scrolled $pos")

                if (posts[pos!!].messageType == "video" || posts[pos].messageType == "messageVideo") { // you might remove this line If you only use video players. But, I needed it.
                    posts[pos].playVideo(posts[pos].playerView!!)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScrolled: played")
                }


                Log.d(TAG, "onScrolled: startCheckPauseTask")
                for (position in posts.indices){
                    if (position == pos) continue

                    posts[position].playerView?.pause()
                    posts[position].playerView?.seekTo(0)
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onScrolled: finishCheckPauseTask")

            }
        })
```

#### Result

---

You can view the result over [here](https://media.giphy.com/media/UTaQv993PIA83fSQsc/giphy.gif)